# Clear setTimeout created from RegisterStartupScript asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, settimeout

I have a refresh being set on an asp.net page like this:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(Page), "Refresh", "<script language='javascript'>setTimeout('document.frmAL.submit();', 60000);</script>")
```

Since I do not have the ID of the settimeout, how do I clear it within vb.net code-behind?  I need to clear it prior to running a semi-long-running SQL command as it is refreshing the page in the middle every now and again :(

Comment: You can create a variable. var timeOut = setTimeout(... and clearTimeout(timeOut)

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that in code-behind with RegisterStartupScript

Comment: When and how do you execute the SQL command?, Can you supply more details about the process, please?